# Advanced REST client (chrome extension) - GET request with params

Tags: node.js, rest, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to simulate GET request with params in the header:
I'm using NodeJS, here is my function:

```
 module.exports.validate = function (req, res, db, callback) {
// if the request dosent have a header with email, reject the request
    if (!req.params.token) {
        res.writeHead(403, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        });
        res.end(JSON.stringify({
            error: "You are not authorized to access this application",
            message: "An Email is required as part of the header"
        }));
    };
    else
       {
         //do something
       }
    };
```

Here is my GET request simulation (by Advanced REST client - chrome extension):

[image]

As you can see, I get 403 because `req.params` ***is undefined***.

My question: How can I add params to the header?  it's look like the email I insert to the header is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your `token` param is since you are not sending it in your request. But if you want to get the email in the request header you should use `req.headers` instead of `req.params`, like this:

```
if (!req.headers.email) {
    res.writeHead(403, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    res.end(JSON.stringify({
        error: "You are not authorized to access this application",
        message: "An Email is required as part of the header"
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is seems like it's immposible to add params to GET req in this extension, looks like an extension bug

Comment: You add GET params by manually putting them on the end of the URL or by clicking the dropdown error to the left of the URL input field.